# TCP server won't work on Openshift NodeJS

Tags: node.js, tcp, openshift

I've used the [openshift-cartridge-tcp-endpoint](https://github.com/Filirom1/openshift-cartridge-tcp-endpoint) cartridge to try and make a TCP server which I can access from a desktop application.

I've set it up on a scaleable application and I can see the OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT_TCP and OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PROXY_PORT_TCP values when I list the environment variables using 'export' when ssh'd into my application.

The problem is, when I do 'rhc ssh APP_NAME oo-gear-registry all', no port is listed over which I can access my TCP application and when I try to access the application over the port given by the HTTP server, it does not connect. Do I have to take additional steps to make the port show up and be accessible?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that cartridge is over 2 years old, and probably doesn't work with the current version of OpenShift Online, as it only exposes port 8080 publicly and uses an HTTP/WS reverse proxy, so only http or web services connections would work.  You might try logging an issue with the cartridge's creator here (https://github.com/Filirom1/openshift-cartridge-tcp-endpoint/issues) and ask them if it still works or not.

Comment: Good suggestion! I did this and will place any results here too for reference.